# Order a query by boxcolumn in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm having trouble to select from tables that contains columns of type BOX on pgsql 9.1

```
create table test (t box);
CREATE TABLE
select * from test order by t;
ERROR:  could not identify an ordering operator for type box
LINE 1: select * from test order by t;
                                     ^
TIP:  Use an explicit ordering operator or modify the query.
```

I figured out that there is a class of operators (box_ops) that should take care of ordering and equality, even tried to create an explicit index for the column.

```
create index testx on test using gist (t box_ops);
CREATE INDEX
```

But the problem is still there. What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve? What should the table you create look like if you're successful?

Comment: The question was about ordering box columns is postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly specify an operator. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY t USING &<
```

You will have to decide what ordering you actually need and choose the corresponding comparison operator.

The operators defined in `box_ops` are available at http://www.leadum.com/downloads/dbscribe/samples/postgresql/web_modern/opclass/main/1325676015.html

See also: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-geometry.html

Comment: Thanks, it solves part of the problem! Now I just need to go a little further: when I'm doing a union select in a table which have box rows, even if I don't order or group by any of those rows, I get the operator error. Is there a way for me to specify the operator pgsql is using implicitly?